# Excel to HTML Table using C#

Tags: c#, html, excel

Is it possible to convert an excel spreadsheet to html code, and if so what would be the best way to do so (basic code to give an idea of how to handle things)? I'm creating a web app that allows a user to upload a spread sheet and output the html code to be copied into a CMS using clean code.

Note: I'm not looking for a full code example or anything, just something to give me the right idea of how to approach this problem.

UPDATE: The answer below accurately sums up what I'm looking for. Pretty much open the file in `memorystream` and then format everything into a table.

Comment: Yes this is possible, what have you tried searching for so far?

Comment: You can start trying with [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) "an open source project which can help you read/write Office 2003/2007 files"

Comment: I've tried searching excel to html table, but everything that I've found has been html table to excel which I already know how to do...I'm guessing I have to open the excel sheet in memorystream then somehow format that into html?

Comment: @Jobokai It's basically just the reverse of the tutorials you found. Get the file, create the document object in your library of choice ([EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), and [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), then iterate through the rows/columns and generate your HTML. Showing you every step for doing that would be a lot to do in one answer. But now that you have a general idea, you should give it a shot and then come to us if you have a specific problem with your implementation.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the info, I just wasn't sure if it'd be something as simple as that. And yes, I wasn't looking for someone to post the code or tutorial since I knew it would be rather lengthy.

Comment: @mason I've edited the question to make it less broad. Let me know if I should add/remove anything to fit the rules.

Comment: @Jobokai It's still too broad. But you've got your answer, so I wouldn't worry about it. It's not going to hurt you, as long as you don't keep making overly broad questions. To avoid making a broad question, your question should be about a specific problem rather than a "point me in the right direction" type question. There is a [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site that is more appropriate for asking what library to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion the most clean and robust solution would be processing an xlsx file in your own method and then returning string with HTML. There's very pleasant package called [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which allows you to easily manage xlsx files. You can easily iterate through columns and rows and generate HTML in any shape you want.

It could look something like that:

```
public string XlsxToHTML(byte[] file)
{
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   stringBuilder.Append("<table>");

   using(ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
   {
      ExcelWorkbook workbook = excelPackage.Workbook;
      if(workbook!=null)
      {
         ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
         if(worksheet!=null)
         {
            var firstCell = worksheet.Cells[1,1].Value;
            var secondCell = worksheet.Cells[1,2].Value;

            stringBuilder.Append("<tr><td>"+firstCell+"</td></tr>");
            stringBuilder.Append("<tr><td>"+firstCell+"</td></tr>");
         }
      }
   }

   stringBuilder.Append("</table>");

   return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Of course it's merely an example. It's dirty because it appends tags and so on, but it's a quick example of the idea...

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I take it this will let me open the excel file and then output html to say a text box/field for a user to copy? I'm not wanting to actually write a file to my server.

Comment: You mean Open Office XML Spreadsheet (.xlsx) file. Most libraries don't support .xls files. I know for a fact that EPPlus doesn't support .xls, but does support .xlsx.

Comment: @Jobokai Yes, these libraries are capable of reading data from files as well as writing to them. They're suitable for either.

Comment: You don't need to write any files to server. You just upload a file through webpage, then server can process it in the memory and output of the method can be plain HTML string. Please make some research about EPPlus and you'll see that iterating over rows and reading values is very easy. Then you can build your HTML table using TagBuilder and/or StringBuilder .NET classess. It will give you freedom to generate HTML as you like.

Comment: @Landeeyo I looked very briefly at EPPlus and that was just something I wanted to get some clarification on.

Comment: @Landeeyo From EPPlus documentation: "reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the **Open Office Xml format (xlsx)**"... so you should correct your answer where you say it manages xls files

Comment: @Jobokai - please find my updated answer, however I'm sure you already got my idea.

Comment: @Landeeyo Yup this was pretty much what I was expecting it to be. Thanks for the update and the code, it will definitely help me get started.